# CSRF in Laravel 5 without cookies

Tags: php, laravel, csrf

I have an application running laravel 5 with CSRF middleware enabled. The application is basically a simple form that asks users for a few inputs. When the submit button is pressed, an AJAX call is made that posts the data back to the application and the form is processed.

The problem is when someone visits the site with their cookies disabled. The CSRF input field in the form contains the value, but when the form is submitted, the server is unable to validate the token because there is no session cookie stored for laravel to access.

Is there any way to keep the CSRF check and allow people with cookies blocked to fill out the form?

Comment: Cookies are a basic requirement of the modern internet. I'd avoid wasting time on those users entirely.

Comment: You could always extend and build upon Laravel's CSRF functionality to bypass cookies, but that would be a lot of work. @ceejayoz makes a valid point. It's 2015.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a middleware that changes the session driver to use the array setting `Config::set('session.driver', 'array');` for the routes you don't want to use cookies on.